# Jetpack Compose AnimatedContent rotation

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

This question is really simple, but the API seems to offer no way to do this / no information on how to do so. Is there any way to achieve rotation animation in a Enter/ExitTransition, e.g. with AnimatedContent, such that, when content is changed, it rotates?